# What type of id i need to chose if i want to work with huge id values in a future [ MySql ]

Tags: mysql

Good day to all. I have big table (40k rows, and 100k++ in a close future) where alot of rows will be deleted (and replaced by modern data), and updated rows by user will be stayed there.

**Question is what type of `id` i need to chose if i want to work with huge id values in a future.**
[image: current MySQL table]

Comment: see here for mysql numeric datatypes. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html. I think you should use a bigint

Comment: i saw this already

Comment: Go for int or bigint
int - -2^31 (-2,147,483,648) to 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647)
bigint - -2^63 (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808) to 2^63-1 (9,223,372,036,854,775,807)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `INT`. It can hold up to 2.1 billion values and most companies never, ever come anywhere close to this. The exceptions to this rule you can basically list on one hand: Google, Facebook, Twitter, Instagram, Tumblr. They'd quickly blow through a billion identifiers. The rest of us this almost never happens.

Remember you can change your primary key type in the future and while this will be annoying, if you actually have enough entries in your database you *need* a `BIGINT` identifier you *will* have more than one database server. You'll probably have *hundreds* of them and even `BIGINT` might not be adequate, you might use something like a UUID instead to avoid collisions.

I can't tell you how many times I've seen a schema with a `BIGINT` in it and after years of regular use it had accumulated only a few thousand identifiers. Clearly someone was planning for their back-office tool to be used by billions of people.

Now there are exceptions to this rule of thumb. If you have a lot of transactional activity where abandoning transactions is a frequent occurrence your `AUTO_INCREMENT` identifiers will have holes in them. In extreme situations you might exhaust your `INT` space 10-20x faster than normal, but even then you get 200 million numbers before you're in trouble.

For some perspective, [Slashdot](http://slashdot.org/), a wildly popular message board system, accidentally used a `MEDIUMINT` for their comment identifiers and [clipped over the maximum value of ~16 million](https://slashdot.org/story/06/11/09/1534204/slashdot-posting-bug-infuriates-haggard-admins) but it took them ten years to do this. 16 million comments is a *lot* of comments.